# How can I order this simple .NET list by two properties?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by, partitioning

Given a list of `Location`'s, I need to do 2 ordering steps.

1. Order by `LocationType` ascending.
2. For each location type value order these results by the `Name` ascending.

Sample data:

```
Location Type | Name
            2 | Templestowe Lower
            2 | Templestowe
            1 | Melbourne
```

Expected results:

```
1. Melbourne
2. Templestowe
3. Templestowe Lower
```

[Here is a (not working) .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0dmjlV)...

and here's the main code (copied from that fiddle)..

```
private class Location
{
    public Location (string name, int locationType)
    {
        Name = name;
        LocationType = locationType;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int LocationType { get; private set;}
}

public static void Main()
{

    var locations = new List<Location> 
    {
        new Location("Templestowe Lower", 2),
        new Location("Templestowe", 2),
        new Location("Melbourne", 1)
    };

    // TODO: return a list, sorted by LocationType and name.
    var results = XXXXX;

    foreach(var location in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(location.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
locations.Sort((x,y) => {
   int delta = x.LocationType.CompareTo(y.LocationType);
   if(delta == 0) delta = string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
   return delta;
});
```

Alternatively:

```
var results = locations.OrderBy(x => x.LocationType).ThenBy(x => x.Name);
```

Or in LINQ syntax (compiles to the same thing):

```
var results = from loc in locations
              orderby loc.LocationType, loc.Name
              select loc;
```

Comment: I think he meant order by location type first, then name. edit: I see you got it :)

Comment: @mot indeed; was fixing that ;p

Comment: @Pure.Krome that would be LINQ. You can also write it a different way; will edit

Comment: Yeah. done lots of LINQ .. just never new of the `ThenBy` clause. Can you please add an edit for also the other way `(from l in locations)` ... ? EDIT: You beat me to it. TA!

Comment: @Pure.Krome `ThenBy` is simply *what LINQ uses* for the additional terms in an `orderby` clause - the first is an `OrderBy`, the rest are `ThenBy`.

Comment: Yep - all works perfectly now :) I've just never stumbled on it after all this time. Wow - so awesome :) :hug:

Answer (score -1):

Check this using group by

```
var results = locations
            .GroupBy(x => x.LocationType)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x=>x.Name));
```